# Get maven build info from rest endpoint using Spring xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

Currently I have this great working solution:

From my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

resources/mvn.build.properties:

```
version=${pom.version}
build.timestamp=${timestamp}
```

BuildInfoProviderImpl.java:

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:mvn.build.properties")
public class BuildInfoProviderImpl implements BuildInfoProvider {

    @Value("${build.timestamp}")
    private String dateTime;
    @Value("${version}")
    private String version;

    private BuildInfo buildInfo;

    @Override
    public BuildInfo getBuildInfo() {
         return buildInfo;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void activate() {
        buildInfo = new BuildInfo(
                LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
                version);
    }
}
```

HealthEndpoint.java:

```
@Service
@Path("_health")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class HealthEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
        HealthEndpoint.class);

    private BuildInfoProvider buildInfoProvider;

    public HealthEndpoint(BuildInfoProvider buildInfoProvider) {
        this.buildInfoProvider = buildInfoProvider;
    }

    @GET
    public BuildInfo getBuildInfo() {
        LOGGER.debug("Build info has been requested");
        return buildInfoProvider.getBuildInfo();
    }
}
```

The question is: How to configure the exactly same thing using xml-configuration file?

I tried to add properties with maven-war-plugin and then get it from my service, but that didn't work at all. It's not seen at classpath. Just for information: It generates under ${baseFolder}/target/{app}.war.

I need something like this, but somehow I have to set maven build properties, everything I tried have failed:

```
<bean id="buildInfoProvider" class="service.impl.BuildInfoProviderImpl"/>

<bean id="healthEndpoint" class="endpoint.HealthEndpoint">
    <constructor-arg ref="buildInfoProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is this a Spring or a Spring Boot application ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I don't actually have correct answer here, I'm gonna provide it myself:

```
public class HealthEndpoint {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthEndpoint.class);

  @Context
  private ServletContext context;

  private BuildInfo buildInfo;

  @GET
  public BuildInfo getBuildInfo() {
    LOGGER.debug("Build info has been requested");
    setBuildInfo();
    return buildInfo;
  }

  private void setBuildInfo() {
    if (buildInfo != null) {
        return;
    }
    // some logic of setting build info with help of manifest file here
  }
}
```

And in my xml configuration I'm just creating this bean like:

```
<bean id="healthEndpoint" class="endpoint.HealthEndpoint"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your application context xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>classpath:mvn.build.properties</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I tried to do this and to set this values as properties, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does you annotation `@PropertySource` works ? if that works than this should work as both are doing the same. Else your specified file is not in classpath

Comment: I not so sure, I should try this once more, also I guess I was trying to do this with getting this from Manifest

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'maven.build.timestamp' in value "${maven.build.timestamp}"